# Copy pasted code of modal from Bootstrap site not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for a while but found no answer to my problem. I'm trying to make a modal but it's not showing up. The code of my modal and the button that triggers the modal are just copy pasted from the official bootstrap site. I don't know what's wrong but if you'd like to know my imports, I've already imported the following (in order):

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`
2. `<script type="text/javascript" href="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>`
3. `<script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
4. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

Please help me.

> EDIT

Here's the code of the modal I copied and pasted

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: open your console and check for errors, if you get an error $ is undefined then your paths for js and css files are invalid. Do try the cdn provided jQuery and bootstrap versions and run your code.

Comment: @PeterDarmis Nope, very clear console sir.

Comment: check `network` in your browser's `developers tools`, if your js and css files are not loading it will show there. Have you tried adding the cdn urls of bootstrap and jQuery? https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js i think you won't have a problem trying your modal using the above urls

Comment: @PeterDarmis no errors. And yes, I've tried but still it didn't showed up :(

Comment: do you have javascript disabled in your browser???

Comment: Could you please post some more of your code or provide more info regarding this problem.

Comment: provide `style.css` full code or Check that in your `style.css` you do not override any basic Bootstrap modal class by setting it for example with `display:none;`

Comment: Did you really download the bootstrap CSS, the bootstrap js and also the jQuery js? Because your code says they are in basucally the same place as your HTML file.

Comment: @takendarkk Yes I did download them. What do you mean by "they are in basucally the same place as your HTML file" sir?

Answer (score 0):

Add [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) and [Bootstrap](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) links properly. Using the CDN provided latest versions of the above your example works fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Check that in your `style.css` you do not override any basic Bootstrap modal class by setting it for example with `display:none;`

Comment: your example works fine tested in firefox and chrome check your system or try your fiddle url with another device. I am posting an image from your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when adding a modal from the example while following a Udacity tutorial on basic html and css. I added these lines of code and it worked:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I thought for sure that I had included the modal in my customized download of the bootstrap edition so I didn't think they would help, but as soon as I added these lines in the header, it worked as I intended. For a more precise example of how to add this to the header:

```
<head>
    <!--these 3 added imports made the modal work-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>MyAwesomeWebpage</title>
</head>
```

PS Don't forget your other style sheets and javascript documents.